# On 'click' not firing/finding Datatable child row to open up

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Here's all the code.

```html
@model IEnumerable<Arb.Models.Fixture>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Fixtures";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<table id="fixtures" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Fixture</th>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Selection</th>
            <th>Bookie</th>
            <th>Coupon</th>
            <th>Back</th>
            <th>Lay</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Percent</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
<style type="text/css" class="init">   
td.details-control {
    background: url('http://next.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('http://next.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
</style>

    <script>

        /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
        function format(d) {
            // `d` is the original data object for the row
            return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Full name:</td>' +
                    '<td>' + d.name + '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Extension number:</td>' +
                    '<td>' + d.extn + '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
                    '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
            '</table>';
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var fixtureTable = $('#fixtures').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/fixtures",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        "className": 'details-control',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                    {
                        data: "eventName",
                        render: function (data, type, fixture) {
                            return "<a href='/fixtures/edit/" + fixture.id + "'>" + fixture.eventName + "</a>";
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'eventDateTime',
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            var d = new Date(data);
                            return d.getDate() + '-' + ('0' + d.getMonth()).slice(-2) + ' ' + ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
                        }
                    },
                    { data: 'marketName' },
                    { data: 'selectionName' },
                    { data: 'bookmakerName' },
                    { data: 'couponName' },
                    {
                        data: 'backOdds',
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2)
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'exchangeType.layOdds',
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2)
                    },

                    {
                        data: 'exchangeType.size',
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('', '.', 0, '£')
                    },
                    {
                        data: null,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return Math.round((row.backOdds / row.exchangeType.layOdds) * 100 - 100) + '%';
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "order": [[1, 'asc']]
            });
            setInterval(function () {
                fixtureTable.ajax.reload(null, false); // user paging is not reset on reload

                var currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {
                    hour: "numeric",
                    minute: "numeric",
                    second: "numeric"
                });

                var currentDate = new Date();

                var datetime = "Last Updated: " + currentDate.getDate() + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)
                + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear() + "  " + currentTime;
                $("#UpdateTime").text(datetime);
            }, 10000);

            // Add event listener for opening and closing details

            $('#fixtures tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);
                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

One thing I have noticed is that sometimes but not always it is showing "selector td.details-control is already specified earlier". But when I look for any earlier definitions including global searching or commenting out code - the error still appears.
[image]
IDK, if this is a red herring, but, it's not getting the child row somehow.

This is what I am trying to achieve https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: can you create fiddle for your code??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that following could be mistakes:

1. with ajax update - you tbody will be recreated, so your event will not work (try to use  `$('#fixtures').on('click', 'tbody td.details-control', ...`
2. `var row = table.row(tr);` - should be `var row = fixtureTable.row(tr);`

Comment: Number 2 worked beautifully -thank you so much kva - you've no idea how much that rescued me!

Only slight issue now is that the 10 seconds auto refresh is closing the child row when it is open at the time of the datatables refresh.

Is there anyway of preventing that - retaining the auto refresh without the open child row closing?

Or am I expecting too much in this case and it is working as it should be and this is the nature of the refresh?

Comment: Seems state for child row (hidden or not) is not saved between ajax reload.
But you can try this:
1. before ajax reload - save opened children
2. call ajax reload with callback (first parameters)
[link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())
In callback function - restore opened children (using saved information)